# Using column name of dataframe as predictor variable in linear regression

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to loop through all the column names of my data.frame and use them 
as predictor variable in a linear regression.

What I currently have is:

```
for (i in 1:11){
for (j in 1:11){
if (i != j ){
  var1 = names(newData)[i]
  var2 = names(newData)[j]
  glm.fit = glm(re78 ~  as.name(var1):as.name(var2), data=newData)
  summary(glm.fit)
  cv.glm(newData, glm.fit, K = 10)$delta[1]
  }
 }
}
```

Where newData is my data.frame and there are 11 columns in total. This code gives me the following error:

Error in model.frame.default(formula = re78 ~ as.name(var1), data = newData,  : 
  invalid type (symbol) for variable 'as.name(var1)'

How can I fix this, and make it work?

Comment: The way in which you used `:` may not work.  May be you need the index of the column names and then use `paste` to create the formula

Comment: Just tried the following:

glm.fit = glm(re78 ~ as.name(var1), data=newData)

still gives me the same error.

Comment: How should I use `paste`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fit <- glm(as.formula(paste0("re78 ~ ", var1)), data=newData)` as @akrun suggest. Further, you likely do not want to call your object `glm.fit` as there is a function with the same.

Caveat: I do not why you have the double loop and the `:`. Do you not want a regression with a single covaraite? I have no idea what you are trying to achieve otherwise.

Comment: I'm trying to loop through all possible interactions of two variables, and see which one gives the lowest estimated prediction error.

Comment: And, if I'm trying to "paste" e.g. var1 * var2 into the formula, how could this be done? var1 * var2 instead of var1 in the `paste0` gives me the non-numeric argument to binary operator error.

Comment: Argh, then use `as.formula(paste0("re78 ~ ", var1, ":", var2))`. Are you sure you do not want the single terms also instead of just the interaction term by using `*` instead of `:`?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want models that use all combinations of two variables. Here's another way to do that using the built-in `mtcars` data frame for illustration and using `mpg` as the outcome variable.

We get all combinations of two variables (excluding the outcome variable, `mpg` in this case) using `combn`. `combn` returns a list where each list element is a vector containing the names of a pair of variables. Then we use `map` (from the `purrr` package) to create models for each pair of variables and store the results in a list.

We use `reformulate` to construct the model formula. `.x` refers back to the vectors of variables names (each element of `vars`). If you run, for example, `reformulate(paste(c("cyl", "disp"),collapse="*"), "mpg")`, you can see what `reformulate` is doing.

```
library(purrr)

# Get all combinations of two variables
vars = combn(names(mtcars)[-grep("mpg", names(mtcars))], 2, simplify=FALSE)
```

Now we want to run regression models on all pairs of variables and store results in a list:

```
# No interaction
models = map(vars, ~ glm(reformulate(.x, "mpg"), data=mtcars))

# Interaction only (no main effects)
models = map(vars, ~ glm(reformulate(paste(.x, collapse=":"), "mpg"), data=mtcars))

# Interaction and main effects
models = map(vars, ~ glm(reformulate(paste(.x, collapse="*"), "mpg"), data=mtcars))
```

Name each list element with the formula for that model:

```
names(models) = map(models, ~ .x[["terms"]])
```

To create the model formulas using `paste` instead of `reformulate` you could do (change `+` to `:` or `*`, depending on what combination of interactions and main effects you want to include):

```
models = map(vars, ~ glm(paste("mpg ~", paste(.x, collapse=" + ")), data=mtcars))
```

To see how `paste` is being used here, you can run:

```
paste("mpg ~", paste(c("cyl", "disp"), collapse=" * "))
```

Here's what the first two models look like when the models include both main effects and the interaction:

```
models[1:2]
```

> ```
> $`mpg ~ cyl * disp`
>
> Call:  glm(formula = reformulate(paste(.x, collapse = "*"), "mpg"), 
>     data = mtcars)
>
> Coefficients:
> (Intercept)          cyl         disp     cyl:disp  
>    49.03721     -3.40524     -0.14553      0.01585  
>
> Degrees of Freedom: 31 Total (i.e. Null);  28 Residual
> Null Deviance:        1126 
> Residual Deviance: 198.1  AIC: 159.1
>
> $`mpg ~ cyl * hp`
>
> Call:  glm(formula = reformulate(paste(.x, collapse = "*"), "mpg"), 
>     data = mtcars)
>
> Coefficients:
> (Intercept)          cyl           hp       cyl:hp  
>    50.75121     -4.11914     -0.17068      0.01974  
>
> Degrees of Freedom: 31 Total (i.e. Null);  28 Residual
> Null Deviance:        1126 
> Residual Deviance: 247.6  AIC: 166.3
> ```

To assess model output, you can use functions from the `broom` package. The code below returns data frames with, respectively, the coefficients and performance statistics for each model.

```
library(broom)

model_coefs = map_df(models, tidy, .id="Model")
model_performance = map_df(models, glance, .id="Model")
```

Here are what the results look like for models with both main effects and the interaction:

```
head(model_coefs, 8)
```

> ```
>              Model        term    estimate   std.error statistic      p.value
> 1 mpg ~ cyl * disp (Intercept) 49.03721186 5.004636297  9.798357 1.506091e-10
> 2 mpg ~ cyl * disp         cyl -3.40524372 0.840189015 -4.052950 3.645320e-04
> 3 mpg ~ cyl * disp        disp -0.14552575 0.040002465 -3.637919 1.099280e-03
> 4 mpg ~ cyl * disp    cyl:disp  0.01585388 0.004947824  3.204212 3.369023e-03
> 5   mpg ~ cyl * hp (Intercept) 50.75120716 6.511685614  7.793866 1.724224e-08
> 6   mpg ~ cyl * hp         cyl -4.11913952 0.988229081 -4.168203 2.672495e-04
> 7   mpg ~ cyl * hp          hp -0.17068010 0.069101555 -2.469989 1.987035e-02
> 8   mpg ~ cyl * hp      cyl:hp  0.01973741 0.008810871  2.240120 3.320219e-02
> ```