# Generating all possible interaction terms for model building

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

This was the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71867756/how-to-run-aic-on-anova-output-from-different-models) which was solved by fellow stackoverflow users.

To build the regression model for each PCs and the independent predictors this was used

```
iv <- c("Sex", "fAge", "Index", "Lane", "Gen")  
dv <- paste0('PC', 1:8)
rhs <- unlist(sapply(1:length(iv), function(m) apply(combn(iv, m = m), 2, paste, collapse = ' + ')))
frms <- with(expand.grid(dv, rhs), paste(Var1, Var2, sep = ' ~ '))

models <- lapply(frms, function(x) anova(lm(x, data = mrna.pcs)))
names(models) <- frms
```

Few of the models out which i ran in to test are as such

```
"PC3 ~ Sex + fAge"                      "PC4 ~ Sex + fAge"                      "PC5 ~ Sex + fAge"
```

I was read through how to use interaction terms from one of the [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19271/different-ways-to-write-interaction-terms-in-lm) so I realised I'm missing something like this

```
y ~ r*s
r + s + rs
```

In my case i would like to see something this sort as one of the example.

```
PC6 ~ Sex + fAge + Sex:fAge
```

So how do I generate the all possible interaction term from predictors

Now what I have is no interaction terms in my models.

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.
**Answer Updated**

@Jay.sf suggested example

```
lm(mpg ~ (cyl+disp+hp)^2, data = mtcars)
```

This works exactly what I would expect to be

```
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  5.601e+01  8.556e+00   6.546  7.4e-07 ***
cyl         -4.427e+00  2.474e+00  -1.789   0.0857 .  
disp        -1.184e-01  4.780e-02  -2.476   0.0204 *  
hp          -1.142e-01  7.394e-02  -1.544   0.1352    
cyl:disp     1.439e-02  7.153e-03   2.012   0.0551 .  
cyl:hp       1.556e-02  1.364e-02   1.141   0.2647    
disp:hp     -8.567e-05  2.201e-04  -0.389   0.7005
```

but when i use this as he suggested

```
rhs <- unlist(sapply(1:length(iv), function(m) apply(combn(iv, m = m), 2, paste, collapse = ' * ')))
```

The model output are as such

```
$`PC7 ~ Sex * fAge`

Call:
lm(formula = x, data = mrna.pcs)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         SexM       fAge12       fAge18  SexM:fAge12  SexM:fAge18  
     2.2140      -0.8965      -2.8590      -5.1501       1.9537       3.2378  


$`PC8 ~ Sex * fAge`

Call:
lm(formula = x, data = mrna.pcs)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         SexM       fAge12       fAge18  SexM:fAge12  SexM:fAge18  
     1.0590       0.9449      -2.0983      -0.5103      -1.2526      -2.5817
```

Not as the one which coming from the example i ran. How do i incorporate both of them `+` and `:` in the same code that would fix the problem i think

I think i was running the wrong one here is my outout

```
Response: PC7
           Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Sex         1    21.9  21.898  0.2065 0.6501
fAge        2   388.7 194.371  1.8329 0.1629
Sex:fAge    2    83.4  41.693  0.3932 0.6755
Residuals 182 19300.3 106.046               

$`PC8 ~ Sex * fAge`
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: PC8
           Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Sex         1     7.4   7.393  0.0787 0.7794
fAge        2   236.5 118.261  1.2581 0.2866
Sex:fAge    2    52.3  26.138  0.2781 0.7576
Residuals 182 17107.4  93.996
```

Comment: How many candidate models are you expecting? All possible combinations of `iv` and their interactions returns 2^15 =  32768 models.

Comment: What about `collapse = ' * '`?

Comment: " 2^15 = 32768 models." well then its a bad idea to test each of these its wastage of computational time. "How many candidate models are you expecting? " That part I didn't think about it since I have patient data where I thought I would check all possible combination but I can test that in those which are really showing strong effect ..

Comment: @jay.sf thank you it works it is simple but as a biology person i have to struggle hard for these basics

Comment: @jay.sf when i use as you suggested I get only interaction terms to model such as this `PC1 ~ Sex * fAge"` but  not this `PC1 ~ Sex + fAge +Sex * fAge ` how to get this ?

Comment: @PesKchan Yes you do, it expands itself. Try `lm(mpg ~ hp*am*cyl, mtcars)` and see what happens.

Comment: `(Intercept)           hp           am          cyl        hp:am       hp:cyl       am:cyl    hp:am:cyl  ` yes here it works ..so did i do something wrong?

Comment: @PesKchan You see `hp*am*cyl` similar of what you get in `frms` using `collapse = ' * '`, and I think it will unfold itself in `anova`.

Comment: @jay.sf the problem is solved the anova function was missing in my code now i got it